# Solving an RC Circuit

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm new to Mathematica and I spend a decent amount of time working with circuits, so I figured learning how to solve RC and RLC circuit DE's would be a good starting point. However, I'm really struggling with this:

I have an RC circuit. R is a resistor, C a capacitor, and power is supplied via an alternating-current 2 voltage V =V(t) which depends on time t. I want to solve the differential equation obeyed by the charge q(t) on the capacity using Kirchhoff’s laws for q(t)

Find q(t) given the voltage V(t) = V0cost(wt) (w = omega) with an initial charge on the capacitor q(t=0)=q0

Here's my incomplete attempt

```
RC = 
Vin = 
s = NDSolve[{It'[t] + (1/RC) It[t] == q[t], It[0] == 0, q[0] == 0, 
            WhenEvent[t == 10, q[t] -> 1]}, It, {t, 0, 30}, 
            DiscreteVariables -> q]
```

Comment: Could you write the whole exact mathematical problem that you are trying to solve? What happens at $t=10$?

Answer (score 2):

For a resistor we have the formula (I am using lower case letters,  because I is the imaginary unit in MMA):

```
u= ir[t] r
```

For a capacitor, with ic= current through capacitor and uc voltage across capacitor and c the capacity:

uc'[t] = ic[t] / c

And for the inductor with il= current through and ul= voltage across inductor and l the inductance.

```
ul= l il'[t]
```

As an example we choose a serie circuit , where the current is the same everywhere: `i==ir==ic==il`, the sum of the voltage over the elements is then equal to the external voltage. And we assume that the capacitor is not charged at t==0:

```
u[t]== i[t] r + Integrate[i[tt],{tt,0,t}]/c +l i'[t]
```

This is a integro differential equation, where MMA is not very strong. Therefore we take the derivative to eliminate the integral. However, we must now specify i'[0]:

```
u'[t]== i'[t] r + i[t]/c+l i''[t]
```

For an example we assume c==10^-5, l==10^-2, r==10, i[0]==0, u[t]==1. And what should we take for u'[0] and i'[t]? If we choose u[t]== 1, then u'[t]==0. At t==0 the current is zero and the capacitor uncharged. Therefore, the only voltage comes from the inductance and we have ul[0]== 1== l i'[0]. This gives i'[0]==1/l. With this we have:

```
eq = {0 == i'[t] r + i[t]/c + l i''[t], i[0] == 0, 
    i'[0] == 1/l} /. {c -> 10^-5, l -> 10^-2, r -> 10};
cur = i /. DSolve[eq, i, t][[1]];
Plot[cur[t], {t, 0, 0.01}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

In praxis one often restrict the external voltage to be sinusoidal, what makes the calculation much easier, because Exp[I w t] (=Cos[w t]+ I Sin[w t]) is an eigenfunction of the equation and the belonging eigenvalue is called the transfer function (argument w)